# Is there anything to do with multiple crafting items?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

So it turns out crafting items (crafting kit, alchemy box, ingot press etc.) can be stacked, but I couldn't understand why would I ever want more than one of those. Is there any reason to hold on to spares, or should I just sell them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't yet found any use for the multiples.  I just sell them when I get the chance.

Comment: Right, haven't seen any evidence to the contrary meanwhile so accepting your answer :) though I actually haven't found a way to split stacks of them (can't seem to put one crafting item into another, which is the only way I know of to split stacks), so selling them turns out to be a little problematic.

Comment: I haven't found a way to split them, either, so I usually avoid combining them, if I think about it in time. Barring that, if I see one on the ground and I have a stack of them already, I'll go to the nearest shop, sell the stack, then come back for the single.

Supposedly, they were working on a way to split stacks in the inventory screen, but I haven't seen any evidence that it's been implemented yet.

Comment: @Oak - Little update. I fired Dredmor up the other night for the first time in a while and found that I could split stacks of crafting items by Alt-clicking them in the inventory screen. Happy hunting.

Answer (score 3):

The Tinker's Parts can be used as an ingredient to craft the Trapper's Toolbelt, so that (to the best of my knowledge,) is the only crafting item you would need more than one of (one as an ingredient one to craft,) and might want to keep stacked (until you need it and use the Alt/Apple key to split them.)